# How to find the next k values groupwise in R?

Tags: r

The data is

```
row group id value
1   a     1  TRUE
2   a     2  FALSE
3   a     3  FALSE
4   a     4  FALSE
5   b     5  TRUE
6   b     6  FALSE
7   b     7  TRUE
```

I want to have a new column `i` so that if any `value` of this row and the next two rows (in the same group) is `TRUE`, `i` is `TRUE`, otherwise `i` is `FALSE`.

So the result I want to see is

```
row group id value i
1   a     1  TRUE  TRUE
2   a     2  FALSE FALSE
3   a     3  FALSE FALSE
4   a     4  FALSE FALSE
5   b     5  TRUE  TRUE
6   b     6  FALSE TRUE
7   b     7  TRUE  TRUE
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: In the example you give and according to your characterisation of `i`, all elements of the column `i` should be `FALSE`. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @tictocchoc For row 1, I want to check `value` from row 1 to row 3 so `i` is `TRUE`. For row 3, `i` depends on `value` from row 3 to row 4 (row 5 belongs to `group` b) so `i` is `FALSE`.

Comment: If you're willing to use a package, here's the data.table way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33312906

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollapply` with `ave` as the grouping function; By default, `rollapply` gives `n+1-window_size` elements, in order to calculate the tail elements correctly, you can align the result to the left and specify partial is `TRUE` so that window less than the specified window size can also be calculated:

```
library(zoo)
df$i <- with(df, ave(value, group, FUN=function(x) rollapply(x, 3, any, partial=T, align="left")))
df

#  row group id value     i
#1   1     a  1  TRUE  TRUE
#2   2     a  2 FALSE FALSE
#3   3     a  3 FALSE FALSE
#4   4     a  4 FALSE FALSE
#5   5     b  5  TRUE  TRUE
#6   6     b  6 FALSE  TRUE
#7   7     b  7  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
setDT(df)[, i := rollapply(value, 3, partial = TRUE, any, align = 'left'), group]
df
#   group id value     i
#1:     a  1  TRUE  TRUE
#2:     a  2 FALSE FALSE
#3:     a  3 FALSE FALSE
#4:     a  4 FALSE FALSE
#5:     b  5  TRUE  TRUE
#6:     b  6 FALSE  TRUE
#7:     b  7  TRUE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

It's doable in base R but can be a little messy. Basically, it involves splitting `df` on `group` and then checking for the rows of each sub-group if the condition is met.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$group), function(a)
    cbind(a, i = sapply(1:NROW(a), function(i)
        sum(a$value[i:min(length(a$value),i+2)])) > 0)))
#    group id value     i
#a.1     a  1  TRUE  TRUE
#a.2     a  2 FALSE FALSE
#a.3     a  3 FALSE FALSE
#a.4     a  4 FALSE FALSE
#b.5     b  5  TRUE  TRUE
#b.6     b  6 FALSE  TRUE
#b.7     b  7  TRUE  TRUE
```

You can modify the above approach to use with `aggregate` too

```
unlist(aggregate(df$value, by = list(df$group), function(a)
    sapply(1:length(a), function(i)
        sum(a[i:min(length(a),i+2)])) > 0)[,2])
#  11    12    13    14    21    22    23 
#TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), 
    id = 1:7, value = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE)), .Names = c("group", "id", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Now THAT is a hell of a one-liner :D

Answer (score 1):

Ok we've seen pretty efficient and hi-level solutions... Now how about an old-school, low-level solution?

So here we go...

#### Create data frame

```
dat <- read.table(text="row group id value
1   a     1  TRUE
2   a     2  FALSE
3   a     3  FALSE
4   a     4  FALSE
5   b     5  TRUE
6   b     6  FALSE
7   b     7  TRUE
", head = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### Find groups cutoff points

```
cutoffs <- 0
for (i in 2:(length(dat$group))) {
  if (dat$group[i] != dat$group[i-1]) {
    cutoffs <- append(cutoffs, i - 1)
  }
}
cutoffs <- c(cutoffs, nrow(dat)) # c(0, 4, 7)
```

#### Generate the sequences to be used for each row

That's the fun part, had to think a little bit for this one!

```
seqs <- list()
cutoff_pos <- 1
while (cutoff_pos < length(cutoffs)) {
  a <- cutoffs[cutoff_pos]     # a = left bound of sequence
  b <- cutoffs[cutoff_pos + 1] # b = right bound of sequence
  while (a != b) {
    next_seq <- (a+1):b
    seqs[[length(seqs) + 1]] <- 
      next_seq[1:min(length(next_seq),3)]
    a <- a + 1
  }
  cutoff_pos <- cutoff_pos + 1
}
```

#### Here's what the sequences look like

```
seqs

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5 6 7

[[6]]
[1] 6 7

[[7]]
[1] 7
```

#### Finally, do the check using our calculated sequences

```
dat$i <- NA
for (r in seq_len(nrow(dat))) {
  dat$i[r] <- any(dat$value[seqs[[r]]])
}
```

#### Resulting dataset

```
  row group id value     i
1   1     a  1  TRUE  TRUE
2   2     a  2 FALSE FALSE
3   3     a  3 FALSE FALSE
4   4     a  4 FALSE FALSE
5   5     b  5  TRUE  TRUE
6   6     b  6 FALSE  TRUE
7   7     b  7  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Disclaimer**: I totally agree, the **datatables** solution by @akrun is by far preferable to this, but I found this problem interesting enough to try and solve it using just base R.

Answer (score 0):

```
mydatatxt <- "
row group id value
1   a     1  TRUE
2   a     2  FALSE
3   a     3  FALSE
4   a     4  FALSE
5   b     5  TRUE
6   b     6  FALSE
7   b     7  TRUE
"
mydata <- read.table(header=T, text=mydatatxt)

group <- table(mydata$group)
ano <- c()
result <- list()
for (i in names(group)){
    variable <- data.frame()
    variable <- mydata[mydata$group == i,]
    len <- nrow(variable)
    ano <- c()
    for (j in 1:len){
        if (j < len - 1){
            ano[j] <- variable$value[j] | variable$value[j+1] | variable$value[j+2]
        }
        if (j == len -1){
            ano[j] <- variable$value[j] | variable$value[j+1]
        }
        if (j == len){
            ano[j] <- variable$value[j]
        }
    }
    result[[i]] <- cbind(variable, ano)
}

# lastly, you can rbind all the dataframe in the result list
```

you can see the result of result

```
$a
  row group id value   ano
1   1     a  1  TRUE  TRUE
2   2     a  2 FALSE FALSE
3   3     a  3 FALSE FALSE
4   4     a  4 FALSE FALSE

$b
  row group id value  ano
5   5     b  5  TRUE TRUE
6   6     b  6 FALSE TRUE
7   7     b  7  TRUE TRUE
```

And use a `for` loop to `rbind` every dataframe in list `result`.